# Scheme rewrite let* as nested unary lets

Tags: scheme, racket, let, rewriting

I have written a function **`match-rewriter`** that is essentially `match-lambda` except that it returns its argument if no match is found:

```
(define-syntax match-rewriter
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (patt body) ...)
      (λ (x) (match x (patt body) ... (_ x))))))
```

Now I would like to use `match-rewriter` to take strings representing source code for `let*` and rewrite it as nested unary `lets`:

```
(define let*→nested-unary-lets
  (match-rewriter (`(let*((,<var> ,<val>) ...) ,<expr1> ,<expr2> ...)
```

I am really stumped over how to pattern match this.  I need to return:

```
`(let((,<var1> ,<val1>)) let((,<var2> ,<val2>)) let((...)) ... )...) ,<expr1> . ,@<expr2>)
```

But the nesting has me stumped.  Any advice is appreciated.

---

Okay, here is my best attempt:

```
(define let*→nested-unary-lets
  (match-rewriter
   (`(let* (()) ,<expr1> ,<expr2> ...)
   (`(let () ,<expr1> . ,<expr2>)))
   (`(let* ((,<var1> ,<val1>) (,<var2> ,<val2>) ...) ,<expr1> ,<expr2> ...)
    `(let ((,<var1> ,<val1>) (let*→nested-unary-lets 
                               '(let* ((,<var2> ,<val2>) ...) ,<expr1> . ,<expr2>)))))
   ))
```

But this is how it behaves:

> (let*→nested-unary-lets '(let* ((a 1) (b (+ a 1)) (c (+ a b))) (displayln c)))
>   '(let ((a 1)
>          (let*→nested-unary-lets
>           '(let* (((b c) ((+ a 1) (+ a b)))
>                   ...)
>              (displayln c)))))

I am confused about the order of the arguments in:

```
(let* (((b c) ((+ a 1) (+ a b)))
```

It seems to me it should be:

```
(let* ((b (+ a 1)) (c (+ a b)))
```

Also, it would be nice if the call to `let*→nested-unary-lets` would execute instead of just printing as text.

Comment: This is going to be quite involved.  It's possible, compilers do it, but it's not straightforward.  Consider if `<val1>` references `<var2>`.  You will have to do a fixpoint factorization.  Wish I had time to fill you in on more details.

Comment: @luqui: Forward references are not allowed in `let*` -- you can only refer to earlier variables.  If `var1` used the variable `var2` anywhere, it would refer to a binding outside the `let*`.

Comment: @Jeremiah, Oh, that should be easy then. `let*` is the recursive one right?  I assumed worked like `let` in Haskell.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @luqui: Yes, `let*` is the recursive one, and I agree that it should be easy to do.

Comment: no, [`letrec`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html) is the recursive one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this; it shouldn't be too difficult.  Specifically, the key idea you need here is not to try to handle the whole list at once.  Instead, your patterns should separate the first binding from the rest, and then wrap one let around a *recursive call* to let*->nested-unary-lets.

Let me know if you have trouble formulating this.

Comment: Thanks.  I considered this but I wasn't sure I could pattern match recursively -- I figured it would need some kind of letrec transformation.  Do you know if there is a way to make an argument to a pattern match optional?  I am tryin to write cond as an if statement but I can't figure out how to make the else-clause optional in the pattern match.

Comment: Yes, I am definitely having trouble with this.  See my edit to the original question for my best guess.

Comment: Okay.  I have figured out the pattern.  My only remaining question is whether or not it's possible to have the recursive call to let*→nested-unary-lets evaluate.

Comment: Hey: would you consider checking the "check" box next to this (or some other) answer? It'll give you a warm fuzzy feeling, and it will allow me to vote for Eli's synonym proposal.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a definition of `let*` in `syntax-rules`-like pseudocode that you can use to write your own version:

```
(let* ((a b) (c d) ...) body ...) === (let ((a b)) (let* ((c d) ...) body ...))
(let* () body ...) === body
```

You should be able to turn that into a function using `match` or a macro using `syntax-rules`.