# Scheme let* as nested unary lets

Tags: scheme, racket, let, rewriting

As an exercise I am trying to rewrite strings representing source code for `let*` as nested unary lets.  Here is my best effort:

```
(define let*→nested-unary-lets
  (match-lambda
   (`(let* (()) ,<exprs>)
   `(let () ,<exprs>))
   (`(let* ((,<var> ,<val>)) ,<exprs>)
   `(let ((,<var> ,<val>)) (let () ,<exprs>)))
   (`(let* ((,<var> ,<val>) ,<clauses>) ,<exprs>)
   `(let ((,<var> ,<val>)) (let*→nested-unary-lets '(let* (,@<clauses>) ,<exprs>))))))
```

The problem I am experiencing at the moment is that the pattern:

```
`(let* ((,<var> ,<val>) ,<clauses>) ,<exprs>)
```

does not match a string like:

```
'(let* ((a b) (c d) (e f)) <expressions>)
```

The term *clauses* matches only the second clause `(c d)`.  It seems to me that it should take all of the remaining `(var val)` clauses as a list `((c d) (e f))`.  At any rate I need it to do so.

Any advice is appreciated.

What baffles me is that *exprs* will match a list of expressions so I can't think of any reason why *clauses* wouldn't also do so.

Comment: this is a followup question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112623/scheme-rewrite-let-as-nested-unary-lets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need `. ,<clauses>` since you want to match the rest of the list, not just a single element.  The `,<exprs>` part will need to be `. ,<exprs>` for the same reason.  I believe there is other syntax specifically for matching lists, but using `.` is simple and matches how lists are implemented internally.

Comment: Thanks.  The "." did the trick.  Strangely <exprs> works just fine without it -- which was confusing me.

Comment: @Schemer: That's probably only because you're trying a `let*` with one expression in the body.  Try `(let* ((a (+ 2 3)) (b (* 6 7))) (display (- b a)) (newline))` without the `.` before `,<exprs>` and see if that works.